# Почему страница залезает под полосу прокрутки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки. Я ставил всем элементам ширину окна 99vw, добавлял отступы - ничего не помогло. Было бы хорошо, если бы были названы варианты причины, но если без верстки не получится, скину в комментарии ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости, управляющие элементы слайдера (стрелки) вынесены за его пределы. Вы можете обернуть слайдер в родительский блок, задать ему width: 100% и overflow: hidden.

Либо покопаться в стилях, перенести стрелки внутрь слайдера.

Дело может быть, конечно, вовсе и не в слайдере. Если лень искать, какой конкретно блок даёт горизонтальную прокрутку, можете весь контент обернуть в родителя с overflow-x: hidden

Comment: Большое спасибо)) Весь контент обернул в один контейнер и задал overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: @НикитаПопов, да, самое простое решение :)